# Deleting auto created model which is under PROTECTED ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, foreign-key-relationship

```
class Basket:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

class Apple:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    basket = models.ForeignKey(Basket, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

...

```
myapple = new Apple(name="my")
myapple.save()
```

...

```
auto_created_basket = myapple.basket
myapple.basket = existing_basket
auto_created_basket.delete()
```

I try to swap out the auto_created_basket to another one, but I get an error when I try to delete it.

`"Cannot delete some instances of model 'Basket' because they are referenced through a protected foreign key: 'Apple.basket'", [<Apple: My apple>])`

Comment: This is because the foreign key  in apple references something in basket so, if you delete basket then that variable in apple will be confused.

Comment: first: `myapple = new Apple(name="my")` will throw a syntax error. Remove `new`. Second: you should specify in which basket the Apple should be inserted. `Apple(name='my', basket=b)` where `b` is an actual basket instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to answer my question, but my example was too over simplified. The answers are very good points.

In the real product there are `post_save` signals involved, responsible for the creation of the `auto_created_basket` for example.

The problem is that when I say `myapple.basket = existing_basket` Django's layer is fine, but the DB is still holding the reference to older relation. The solution in my case was to move the `auto_created_basket.delete()` after I save `myapple` once more.

Answer (score 7):

In your `Apple` model the `basket` field is a foreing key

```
basket = models.ForeignKey(Basket, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

whose `on_delete` attribute value specifically states to protect the apples by preventing the deletion of the basket, i.e. the basket cannot be deleted as long as an apple is still in it.

As the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) say

> When an object referenced by a ForeignKey is deleted, Django by
> default emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint ON DELETE CASCADE
> and also deletes the object containing the ForeignKey.

and

> the PROTECT parameter prevents deletion of the referenced object by raising
> ProtectedError

So, the easiest step should be to remove the `on_delete` parameter and go with the default behaviour

```
basket = models.ForeignKey(Basket)
```

**However**, please have a look at all the possible parameters to a [ForeignKey model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) and choose the combination that suits the requirements of your application/scenario.

**UPDATE:**

Recent Django versions require `on_delete`. Just don't remove it and add the parameter you want (like `on_delete=models.CASCADE`).

Comment: Just a quick comment since this answer ranks pretty high on google and contains a logic error: The `on_delete` does not specify that the `Apple` should not be deleted when the `Basket` is deleted: Instead it specifies that the `Basket` cannot be deleted as long as an `Apple` is still in it. Your official documentation quote states that as well, just the explanation above contradicts it :-) - great answer otherwise

Answer (score 2):

You can try moving apples from `auto_created_basket` into `existing_basket` before deleting the basket first:

```
>>> auto_created_basket.apple_set.update(basket=existing_basket)
>>> auto_created_basket.delete()
```

or

```
>>> myapple.basket = existing_basket
>>> myapple.save()
>>> auto_created_basket.delete()
```

Alternatively, if you want to collect apples that are from deleted baskets in a single basket, you can assign a function to `on_delete` property as follows:

```
def get_sentinel_basket():
    basket, created = Basket.objects.get_or_create(name='DELETED')
    return basket
```

--

```
basket = models.ForeignKey(Basket, on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel_basket))
```

so when a basket is deleted, the `.basket` attribute of apples in that basket will automatically be set to `Basket(name='DELETED')`.